# Why is my data not passing to my second view controller from a table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass the value to a second view controller

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "headToDetail" {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
            print("SELECTED INDEX \(indexPath)")
            let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
            print("Segue TEst \(self.toPass)")
            destVC.vieSegue = self.toPass
        }
```

I've remove the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and just going to use the Segue but when I tap on a row cell I get:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This is a major update to the original code.

Comment: Why is your prepareForSegue empty ?

Comment: hey, normally you have something like -> override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender);
something = Something();
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController;
        vc.setSomething(something);
    }

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, that you are creating a new `ViewController` at line

```
var destination =  SecondViewController()
```

but then the controller simply deallocates because *nothing is pointing to it* (there is no reference to it and it falls out of scope). You haven't pushed into it, nor you performed any segue.

How to fix it? Basically there are two options.

**Storyboard**

If you're working with storyboards, you have to create a segue between the first `ViewController` and `SecondViewController`. You have to give it an `identifier`.

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you will write

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row
    print(fruits[row])
    self.toPass = fruits[row]

    performSegueWithIdentifier("YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER", sender: nil)
}
```

then in `prepareForSegue` you'll set the property to the destination `SecondViewController`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        destVC.vieSegue = self.toPass!
    }
}
```

**Manual Push**

The second option is to push the controller manually within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row
    print(fruits[row])

    let destination =  SecondViewController()
    destination.vieSegue = fruits[row]

    // if you are using navigation controller
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

    // if you want to present it modally
    // presentViewController(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The second version doesn't force you to create segues.

Comment: Hi David. 
I followed your code however it doesn't not seem to work . I didn't think you needed the performSegueWithIdentitfier if you had it hooked up in the storyboard. I'm still not able to pass the data. What is weird is that I have print statements and when I click on the table row. Seems like the override func prepareForSegue is running before the didSelectRowAtIndex path

Comment: Well, that shouldn't happen. You need the `performSegueWithIdentifier` if your segue isn't wired to a button or something similar that may produce the segue action. If it is wired to such a thing, you can change it to be wired only between the two controllers. Anyways, if this doesn't work, try the second approach with instantiating the `SecondViewController` manually. Though if you have your controller in storyboard, you will have to use `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Hi David. Did you the above change to the code. I read online that you shouldn't really have both of those methods at the same time. And it is dependant on whethere you set up the segue from the tableview to the second controller or the view controller to the other viewcontroller.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that. Can you post the link? And as I mentioned, there are two options (storyboard and manual push), they are kind of mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

It's empty because you create a new object...

```
var destination =  SecondViewController()
```

...pass it your data...

```
destination.vieSegue = self.toPass!
```

...and then let it go out of scope without showing it, saving it, or doing anything else useful.